# A quick question on inequalities with floor function.

Tags: inequality

For any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, denote $\lfloor x\rfloor:=\max\{n\in\mathbb{Z}\mid n\leq x\}$, i.e. the floor function.

Show that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $m\leq n$

$$\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor+1}{n}\leq\frac{\lfloor mx\rfloor+1}{m}.$$

I tried to show this directly and by contradiction but seem to get nowhere, so any help is greatly needed. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think that this is true.  If $x = 1/3, m=2,n=3$ we have that the left hand side is $2/3$. and the right-hand side is $1/2$.

Comment: I have this strange feeling that the floor functions are switched but then that would be too easy...

Comment: I am trying to show that $\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{n}\downarrow x$, so it is obvious that it converges to $x$, but is it a decreasing sequence for big enough $n$, or should we use the ceiling function instead and will that give us a decreasing sequence?

Comment: @Fred I think it's not eventually monotonic either way.  If you are trying to show convergence I think you should do so directly, as $\frac{\lfloor nx \rfloor}{n} \in \left(x-\frac{1}{n}, x\right)$

Comment: I have a right-continuous function so need a decreasing sequence, would using the ceiling function instead work?

Answer (score 1):

Take $x=1.1$, $m=9$, $n=10$.

Then, we have that

$$\frac{\lfloor11\rfloor+1}{10}=1.2>\frac{\lfloor9.9\rfloor+1}{9}=1.111\ldots$$

In other words, it is false.

You can find more counterexamples choosing $x$, $m$ and $n=m+1$ such that $mx$ has a "big" (next to $1$) fractional part and $nx$ has it small.

Answer (score 0):

The claim in the problem is false as shown by the counter-example Rolf Hoyer provided in the comments. However, the following claim is true:

> **Claim:**
>   $$\frac{\lfloor mx\rfloor+1}{n}\leq\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor+1}{m}$$

**Proof:**

$$\forall~m,n\in\Bbb{N}~\mid m\leq n\implies mx\leq nx~\forall~x\in\Bbb{R}$$

$$mx\leq nx\implies \lfloor mx\rfloor\leq \lfloor nx\rfloor\implies \lfloor mx\rfloor+1\leq \lfloor nx\rfloor+1\tag1$$

Now, we also have,

$$m\leq n\iff \frac{1}{m}\geq \frac{1}{n}\iff \frac{1}{n}\leq \frac{1}{m}\tag2$$

Now, we use the following identity on $(1)$ and $(2)$:

> $$a\leq b~\land~c\leq d\implies ac\leq bd$$

Using that we get,

$$\frac{\lfloor mx\rfloor+1}{n}\leq\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor+1}{m}$$

Comment: @ajotatxe, I think it's corrected now. Can you please verify?

Comment: I find it OK, but I'm not sure if this is what OP wants. Worth a try, anycase.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but will the original claim be true if we used the ceiling function, i.e. $\lceil x\rceil=\max\{n\in\mathbb{Z}|n\geq x\}$ I need to construct a decreasing sequence.

Comment: @Fred, I think you meant $\lceil x\rceil=\color{red}{\min}\{n\in\Bbb Z\mid n\geq x\}$. And regarding that, let me see if I can find a counter-example to that or else a proof of that. :)

Comment: Yes, sorry I did mean $\lceil x\rceil:=\min\{n\in\mathbb{Z}|n\geq x\}$. Any luck in finding a proof for the claim if the ceiling is used or a counter-example?

Comment: Hi, Can you please answer this question? I think you can help me http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1693969/322103